# Passing JSP parameters from one jsp to another : code uses HIPPO

Tags: jsp, parameters, hippocms

I am trying to pass a parameter from one jsp file to another using

From Index.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp">
   <jsp:param name="main" value="true"/>
</jsp:include>
```

And then Accessing param main in footer.jsp using

```
  <h1>The value : ${param.main}</h1>
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.main=='true'}">
      something
    </c:when>
```

however, param.main still remains null in footer.jsp.

Our code uses HIPPO CMS. Is there a way I can send a parameter from one jsp to another in HIPPO CMS. I tried searching but i could not find anything relavant to HIPPO CMS.

Comment: what does this do if you add it to the footer.jsp -  

   <c:forEach items="${param}" var="p">  
        <tr>  
            <td>${p.key}</td>  
            <td>${p.value}</td>  
        </tr>  
    </c:forEach>

Comment: Is this an example or is it your real code? I would try antonyn's suggestion since it should work.

Answer (score 2):

We used taglibs for this. It worked.

Create a tag file footer.tag (This file will resemble footer.jsp)

Then in index.jsp include the tag file using

```
<customTag:footer main="true"/>
```

(Custom Tag denotes the folder in which your footer.tag is being kept)

This will include the footer tag in the index.jsp and parameters can be passed as mentioned above.

A sample of the footer tag :

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" prefix="x"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.hippoecm.org/jsp/hst/core" prefix='hst'%>

<%@ attribute name="main" required="false"%>

<p>The value of main is ${main}</p>
```

Comment: It is horrible workaround. There is no other way to pass a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue using following code:

```
<c:set var="name" value="${value}" scope="request" />
<jsp:include page="page.jsp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hippo wraps HttpServletRequest with it's own request and adds a prefix for attribute name to access attribute with same name in different components (or browser windows). But all of this can not stop you for using pure `HttpServlet.setAttribute` - just get `RequestContext` from `HstRequest` and then get `HttpServletRequest`:

```
HstRequest hstRequest = ...
hstRequest.getRequestContext().getServletRequest().setAttribute("attributeName", new Object());
```